# Initialization of flexible array member is not allowed

Tags: c, struct, flexible-array-member

I found a [GNU C documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#:%7E:text=6.18%20Arrays%20of%20Length%20Zero,for%20a%20variable%2Dlength%20object%3A&text=Accessing%20elements%20of%20zero%2Dlength,undefined%20and%20may%20be%20diagnosed.) on flexible arrays, and they say that you can initialize them like that:

```
struct foo { int x; int y[]; };
struct bar { struct foo z; };

struct foo a = { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } };        // Valid.
struct bar b = { { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } } };    // Invalid.
struct bar c = { { 1, { } } };            // Valid.
struct foo d[1] = { { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } } };  // Invalid
```

But when I try to do the first valid case (with struct `a`), gcc throws `error: Initialization of flexible array member is not allowed`. So is this deprecated or is there another way to do it without `malloc`?

Comment: This is not reproducible. [Godbolt shows GCC 11.1](https://godbolt.org) complaining about the initializations of `b` and `d`, as the documentation indicates, and not about `a` and `c`. What version of GCC are you using and with which switches?

Comment: This is found in the chapter called "C extensions". If you compile with strict settings then you cannot use non-standard extensions.

Comment: All elements of an array have to be the same size.  Otherwise, array indexing doesn't work.  Granted, `d` has only one element (why?), but that's why you can't have arrays of structures with flexible array members.   All members of a structure have to be at a known (fixed) offset.  That's why there are limits on nesting structures with flexible array members.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That is not in question. OP does not ask why they cannot initialize an array of structures with flexible array members. The question is just about why the compiler says that initialization of `struct foo a` is not allowed when the GCC documentation says it is.